# Convert Audio to binary Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

I want to upload recorded audio to the server and I was wondering how to convert to binary Data I know for images there is `pngData` is there something smiler for Audio , I try the below code ,but I am not sure if the is the correct way

```
 let fileData = try NSData(contentsOf: filePath!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
 let base64String = fileData.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength76Characters)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert it to data like this

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf:fileUrl) else { return }
```

and upload as a multipart with Alamofire

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    // use this
     multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "audio", fileName: "audio.aac", mimeType: "audio/aac") 

     // or this    
     multipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "audio", fileName: "audio.aac", mimeType: "audio/aac")


} ,to: url,method:.post,
   headers:head,
   encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)") 
        })
        upload.responseJSON { response in

        }
        break
      case .failure(let encodingError): 
        break

     }

})
```